# Time spent in okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders()

Tags: java, okhttp, newrelic

I see in NewRelic that ~90% of the request time is spent in this method. I'm trying to figure out how to optimize this endpoint and am wondering where to start. What does this method do that could take this long?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that have something to do with newrelic itself. Check out this [thread](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/feature-idea-support-okhttp-3-on-java/49182/5)